# A worksheet summaries the information from a range of sheets and to add hyperlink to specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have several sheets behind the content page, and the content page will summarise all specific information of the sheets behind row by row. (this is done already) However, I would like to add a hyperlink to a specific cell of each line of the content page which links to a respective sheet at the back.

But i have syntax error on this row

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("F77").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=_"'worksheets(R)"!A1", TextToDisplay:=cell.Value`

Would you mind teaching me how I can fix this?

Thank you so much in advance and much appreciated!

Please see the code as below:

```
Sub Summary_of_EO_Projects()
Dim EOStartNum, EOEndNum As Long
EOProStartNum = Worksheets("EOStart").Next.Index
EOProEndNum = Worksheets("EOEnd").Previous.Index

Sheets("Summary of EO Projects").Select
Range("A5").Select
Startline = 5

For R = EOProStartNum To EOProEndNum
Range("A" & Startline).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("D4")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("D5")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("F77").Hyperlinks.Add _
                 Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", _
                 SubAddress:="'worksheets(R)"!A1", _
                 TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("G77")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("H77")

Startline = Startline + 1
Range("A" & Startline).Select
Next R


End Sub
```

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of questions and answers on this site showing how to add hyperlinks and explaining how to stop using `.Select` and work against `ActiveCell`. Did you *search* a little? "Excel VBA create hyperlink" should get you somewhere...

Comment: Record a macro while adding a hyperlink, and start with that.

Comment: @TimWilliams  @Mat's Mug Sorry I know it might be easy for you guys, since this is my 2nd VBA, before I posted here, I had searched through and tried recording a macro but I find it appears as "FALES" when i adding the below code after `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets(R).Range("D5")`.... shall I define a cell or add another action to this? Thank you so much. `Range("B5").Select ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _ "'Data Input1", TextToDisplay:= _ "Data Input1"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a utility Sub which I typically use when I need to create hyperlinks:

```
'Create a hyperlink from a cell to a range *in the same workbook*
'  txt = the text to disply in the hyperlink
Sub DoHyperlink(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range, txt As String)
    Dim addr As String
    addr = "'" &amp; rngTo.Parent.Name &amp; "'!" &amp; rngTo.Address(False, False)
    rngFrom.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngFrom, Address:="", _
                            SubAddress:=addr, TextToDisplay:=txt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to study it to see if I can combine it with my code.